# Duda sobre referencia a un objeto dentro de un ArrayList

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, objeto

tengo entendido que en java, si creo una instancia y luego le asigno una nueva referencia, la anterior referencia es eliminada de memoria por el Garbage Collector. Por ejemplo:

```
    Persona per = new Persona();
    per.setNombres("Roberto");
    System.out.println(per.getNombres()); // imprimirá en consola --> Roberto
    
    per = new Persona();
    per.setNombres("Valentina");
    System.out.println(per.getNombres()); // imprimirá en consola --> Valentina
```

En el código de arriba, después de imprimir Valentina sería imposible volver a imprimir el valor Pedro ya que la instancia per ya esta apuntando a un nuevo espacio de memoria, dejando olvidada la anterior referencia. Por lo que el Garbage Collector ya lo eliminó.

Pero pasa algo raro en este escenario.

```
    List<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Persona per = new Persona();
    per.setNombres("Roberto");
    lista.add(per);

    per = new Persona();
    per.setNombres("Valentina");
    lista.add(per);
    
    for (Persona persona : lista) {
        System.out.println(persona.getNombres()); 
    }
    
    // imprimirá en consola --> Roberto
                                Valentina
```

Entonces ahí viene mi duda, como es que se llega a imprimir Roberto si se supone la instancia per apunta a un nuevo espacio de memoria, osea Valentina y dejando olvidado a Roberto.

Agradecería alguien me explique, si existe documentación mejor. De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tú haces un:

```
System.out.println(lista);
```

Verás algo como esto:

```
[Persona@5a07e868, Persona@76ed5528]
```

¿Por qué?

Porque al hacer cada:

```
lista.add(per);
```

Se guardó en `lista` la referencia del objeto `per`, y su existencia en memoria no se destruyó en el segundo:

```
per = new Persona();
```

¿Por qué no se destruyó? Porque ese nuevo `new Persona()` lo que hace es alojar otro espacio en memoria (diferente del primero) para el nuevo objeto.

Eso lo puedes ver con este simple ejemplo:

```
Persona per = new Persona();
per.setNombres("Roberto");
System.out.println(per); 

per = new Persona();
per.setNombres("Valentina");
System.out.println(per);
```

La salida será algo así:

```
Persona@5a07e868
Persona@76ed5528
```

Además, ten en cuenta que el recolector de basura destruye los objetos cuando ya no hay referencia a ellos, cosa que no ocurre aquí: en la lista hay una referencia al primer objeto y tampoco ese objeto **es candidato** a ser destruido por ahora. Y aunque, digamos, hicieras al objeto candidato para que sea destruido, igualándolo a `null` por ejemplo, el hecho de estar en la lista elimina esa candidatura.

Mira este caso:

```
Persona per = new Persona();
per.setNombres("Roberto");
/*Lo metemos en la lista*/    
lista.add(per);
System.out.println("1er per: "+per); 
/*Lo anulamos*/
per=null;
    
System.out.println("1er per anulado: "+per); 

per = new Persona();
per.setNombres("Valentina");
System.out.println("2do per: "+per);         
lista.add(per);
System.out.println("Ambas referencias existen en la lista: "+lista); 

for (Persona persona : lista) {
    System.out.println(persona.getNombres()); 
}
    
    
}
```

**Salida:**

```
1er per: Persona@3af49f1c
1er per anulado: null
2do per: Persona@19469ea2
Ambas referencias existen en la lista: [Persona@3af49f1c, Persona@19469ea2]

Roberto
Valentina
```

Como podrás comprobar, aunque anules el primer `per` éste sigue ahí, porque hay una referencia suya en la lista. Aunque ahora mismo el colector de basura se lanzara a destruir objetos, el primer `per` se salva, porque él sigue estando en la lista.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta, me quedo claro el concepto.

Answer (score 0):

Porque la lista guarda una copia de la referencia.

Tu primer ejemplo lo entiendes bien. Pero si haces

```
Persona per = new Persona();
per.setNombres("Roberto");
System.out.println(per.getNombres()); // imprimirá en consola --> Roberto

Persona per2 = per;
per = new Persona();
```

en `per2` guardas una referencia al objeto original, y puedes accederlo por ahí. El JVM se encarga de anotar que el objeto original todavía tiene una referencia viva. El GC tiene en cuenta esta referencia y no eliminará el objeto.

Al hacer el `lista.add(per)`, la implementación de `ArrayList.add(Object)` crea y mantiene una copia interna de la referencia.

Aparte, un detalle: cuando un objeto se queda sin referencias que apunten a él, es posible que el GC lo elimine. Sin embargo:

- El GC se va ejecutando periódicamente. No es que a cada instrucción se ejecute para eliminar objetos no referenciados.
- El GC no esta obligado, en general, a eliminar todos los objetos no referenciados. Puede ser que se ejecute el GC y algunos objetos no se eliminen, y sean eliminados en ejecuciones posteriores. Estos son detalles de implementación del GC.

  De hecho, se puede configurar la invocación de la JVM para que use una implementación determinada; los diferentes GC ofrecen diferentes características. Pero eso es una cuestión muy avanzada y que solo se usa en escenarios con necesidades muy específicas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Si podríamos decir que guarda una copia por eso aún existe la referencia. También podríamos decir que no se elimina la referencia debido a que el indice del ArrayList esta apuntando hacia ella. Gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que creas una instancia "Roberto" y la agregas en el `ArrayList` mediante el mètodo [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) :

```
List<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<>();

Persona per = new Persona();
per.setNombres("Roberto");
lista.add(per);
```

> [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) Agrega el elemento especificado al final de esta lista.

posteriormente creas otra instancia pero esta tambièn es agregada en el mismo `ArrayList` (`lista`) usando el mètodo [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-)

```
per = new Persona();
per.setNombres("Valentina");
lista.add(per);
```

Lo que estas haciendo es crear una nueva instancia pero las  estas almacenando en el ArrayList

> [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
>
> Implementación de matriz redimensionable de la interfaz List.
> Implementa todas las operaciones de lista opcionales y permite todos
> los elementos, incluido el nulo. Además de implementar la interfaz
> List, esta clase proporciona métodos para manipular el tamaño de la
> matriz que se usa internamente para almacenar la lista. (Esta clase es
> aproximadamente equivalente a Vector, excepto que no está
> sincronizada).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.